# Form validation - in terms of conciseness

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form on a website I wish to validate. It is a simple enough Bootstrap 3 marked up form. Please see the image below.

[image]

As you can see it's nothing too fancy...

In terms of validation what is the right way to write concise code that serves the designated purpose? For instance if I were to have 20 fields, is it appropriate or considered okay to have isset used on every posted variable?

Comment: HTML5 has `required` attribute, did you look that?

Comment: use both client side and server side validation, for server side validation use ajax will help u for user exp...

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically best practice is to have both client-side and server-side validation, so I think the best answer is ***both***.

This is important because, if you just have client-side (JS) validation anyone can go into DevTools and change your form around to avoid the validation rules. This is especially try for spam bots which look for these types of exploits.

Having server side validation in conjunction with your client side solution can ensure quality data being passed into your database.

Hope this helps.